# Updating entry field

Tags: entries, performance, saving

I need to save page views for some pages.

I ended up doing it with this code:

```
{% set pageviews = entry.pageviews %}
{% do entry.setFieldValue('pageviews', pageviews+1) %}
{% do craft.app.getElements().saveElement(entry) %}
```

It's working fine but it slows down significantly the page with an increase of around 100 database queries which I cannot explain.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's natural that you're seeing a lot of extra queries; Craft does a ton of work when saving an entry (creating/pruning revisions, updating search indexes, propagating elements etc). You're probably also going to have your template caches invalidated on every pageload. In short, re-saving entries on every frontend request is a bad idea.

A much better approach is using Craft's [`seq()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#seq) function:

```
{# Increment page views for the current entry, without outputting the current count #}
{% do seq('pageviews:' ~ entry.id) %}

{# Output page views for the current entry, without incrementing #}
{{ seq('pageviews:' ~ entry.id, next=false) }}

{# Increment _and_ output the current count #}
{{ seq('pageviews:' ~ entry.id) }}
```

The `seq()` function doesn't interface with custom fields, though. If you do need to have the page view count stored in a custom field for some reason, a possible workaround in terms of the performance issue is going through the [Content service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-content.html#public-properties) to save the updated custom field value instead of actually re-saving the entry using `craft.app.getElements()`:

```
{% set pageviews = entry.pageviews %}
{% do entry.setFieldValue('pageviews', pageviews+1) %}
{% do craft.app.getContent().saveContent(entry) %}
```

The above is pretty hacky though, and not really a *much* better idea than actually re-saving the entry in full (although it does result in less queries being executed). It's definitely not an approach I would recommend.

*Finally, there's also a few plugins available for storing view counts, for example [this](https://plugins.craftcms.com/view-count) or [this](https://plugins.craftcms.com/entry-count).*

Comment: Great thank you so much! I did not know the seq() function, very useful.